# What is the definition of Trunk Music?

Tags: genre, hip-hop, rap

I searched over internet but couldn't find nothing. Could someone tell me what is Trunk Music? I just listened to Yelawolf?

Edit: Please note that I am not talking about the album. I'm talking about this http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Trunk+music&defid=5855004

E.g. Eminem says in his song *"...Couldn't do nothin' play it off "what you bumpin'?" "**Trunk Muzik**, Yelawolf's better", fuckin' bitch..."*

Here Trunk Music seems to be a specific sub genre.

Comment: Your urban dictionary link seems to already answer your question pretty good. So Trunk Music isn't really a genre defined by the type of music, but more by the type of distribution (selling out of trunk) or the area it comes from. Because of the example sentence on urban dictionary, I'd even say all the underground, local Rap is Trunk Music.

Answer (score 2):

Well, "Bumpin" is a term for "selling".  It's also a term for playing loud music.  And it's well known that Eminem literally sold CDs out of his car trunk after shows.  So it's very possible that he's talking about unsigned bands who don't have a distribution network but still want to get their music heard.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of Yelawolf, you probably are referring to `Trunk Muzik` and not
`Trunk Music`.

[Trunk Muzik 0-60](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trunk_Muzik_0-60) is the second extended play by American rapper Yelawolf. It was released on November 22, 2010, by [Interscope Records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interscope_Records).

Comment: No I am not talking about the album. I'm talking about this http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Trunk+music&defid=5855004